# Indexing of 2D array in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have a 6X4 matrix `M1` containing only zeros. 
I also have two 1D arrays `Y1` and `Y2` each with length 4.The two arrays contain the desired index values. Now, I want to set(convert to 1) the elements of matrix `M1` such that 
`M1(Y1:Y2)` is equal to 1

for ex: `Y1=[1 2 2 1]` and `Y2=[3 4 5 3]`
then, `M1` should be

```
 1 0 0 1
 1 1 1 1 
 1 1 1 1
 0 1 1 0
 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0
```

I can do this using for loop. But is there any optimised way to do it? (I intend to use much bigger matrices)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may be other techniques, but this uses element wise operations which are insanely parallel.

A very simple solution. Thanks @[Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai)

```
>> [rows, cols] = size(M);
>> Y1=[1 2 2 1]; Y2=[3 4 5 3]; 
>> M = bsxfun(@ge, (1:rows)', Y1) & bsxfun(@le, (1:rows)', Y2)
M =
     1     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     0
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0
```

**Unnecessarily complicated code**

```
[rows, cols] = size(M);
offsets = ((1 : cols) - 1) * rows
Y1 = offsets + Y1;
Y2 = offsets + Y2;

M = reshape(1:numel(M), rows, cols);
M = bsxfun(@ge, M, Y1) & bsxfun(@le, M, Y2);
```

Comment: great use of `bsxfun` - but you can do it without using `offsets`

Comment: @shai There is still a bug, I am fixing it.

Comment: an answer for my question can be found if you hover over the bottom of my answer ;-)

Comment: but why the `offset` and all the mess? `bsxfun` can make it one-liner!

Comment: @shai It was the first thing that came to my mind. I see there is a cleaner way to do things :) I will add it that solution as well.

Comment: you got my +1 for having FUN with `bsxfun` ;)

Answer (score 8):

use `cumsum`!

```
>> szM = size(M1);
>> M1( sub2ind( szM, Y1, 1:szM(2) ) ) = 1
M1 =
 1     0     0     1
 0     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
>> M1( sub2ind( szM, Y2+1, 1:szM(2) ) ) = -1
M1 =
 1     0     0     1
 0     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0
-1     0     0    -1
 0    -1     0     0
 0     0    -1     0
>> M = cumsum(M,1)
M =
 1     0     0     1
 1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1
 0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0
```

**A pitfall:**
If any of `Y2` equals 6 than setting `Y2+1` to -1 will exceed matrix dimension.
To fix this you can add two lines before setting to -1 the elements of M:

```
>> cols = 1:szM(2);
>> sel = Y2 < szM(1);
>> M1( sub2ind( szM, Y2(sel)+1, cols(sel) ) ) = -1
```

A spin-off for [Pavan Yalamanchili's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17185386/1714410) using `bsxfun`: (hover to see:)

> using `bsxfun` without `offsets`:
>  `M1 = bsxfun( @ge, (1:size(M1,1))', Y1 ) & bsxfun( @le, (1:size(M1,1))', Y2 );`